# How to specify Python Executable file as Interpreter ArcGIS Pro Custom Script Tool

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I am converting a stand-alone script to a ArcGIS Pro custom script tool. When I run the script, everything runs according to plan, however I get an error when I run it as a tool.

> AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

When running as a stand-alone script, I'm running the code with Spyder and the version of python is 3.7.10. `print(sys.executable)` returns C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\pythonw.exe

When I test this from the python window in ArcGIS Pro directly, they Python version is the same, however `print(sys.executable)` returns C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGISPro.exe. I checked the project environment via Pro > Project > Python and the Project Environment is set to my clone environment (C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone). I'm trying to understand how I can fix this so that I can create and test a script in Spyder and have it perform the same (use the same environment) in Pro.

When I test this on a second computer, the return of `print(sys.executable)` in Spyder is 'C:\Users\MyProfile\MyPrograms\ESRI_ArcGIS_Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3_Clone\python.exe' and for the python window in Pro, it is C:\Users\MyProfile\MyPrograms\ESRI_ArcGIS_Pro\bin\ArcGISPro.exe. And on this second computer, the tool runs the same as the script. The second computer uses Python 3.6.9.

Adding `arcpy.AddMessage("{}".format(sys.path))` to the tool script (run on the first computer) prints out the following message in the tool:
['C:\Users\MyProfile\Documents\Python Scripts',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\DLLs',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\future-0.18.2-py3.7.egg',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pytz-2020.1-py3.7.egg',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py3.7.egg',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\pywin32security',
'C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\sympy-1.5.1-py3.7.egg']

Comment: For the Python window in Pro, you are getting the executable for the ArcGIS Pro application itself, NOT for Python.  It's not really comparable in the same way.

Comment: It's worth noting that Python 2.7 (as per ArcMap) would throw exactly that error if you imported 'urllib' and tried to run 'urllib.request', whereas that is valid syntax for the that module in Python 3.7 (as per ArcGIS Pro).  I'm not sure what that means, but is there some way that the tool could be trying to use an old Python 2.7 (ArcMap) environment?

Comment: @SonofaBeach, thanks I just added the printed message to the question text.

Comment: I see that ArcGIS Pro Python includes urllib3.  What happens if you change your code to import urllib3?  How or why did you install urllib?